# How to Write the Numpy array video to Disk While adding Audio from File using the python ffmpegio

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, video-processing, ffmpeg-python

I Have an A NumPy array Representing the Video in the memory how Can I Use the `ffmpegio` python module to save it on the File on the disk While adding the audio.

I Try Many things. I Also Ask answer on the python-ffmpegio github page.
[Discussinnon link](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio/discussions/21)

The Whole module Code is on the [vidiopy](https://github.com/SohamTilekar/vidiopy)

I Get an Error: -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\soham_code\video_py\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    clip.write_videofile(r'D:\soham_code\video_py\test\test_video.mp4')
  File "d:\soham_code\video_py\vidiopy\video\VideoClips.py", line 190, in write_videofile
    with ffmpegio.open(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ffmpegio\__init__.py", line 324, in open
    stream = StreamClass(*args, **kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ffmpegio\streams\SimpleStreams.py", line 489, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ffmpegio\streams\SimpleStreams.py", line 365, in __init__
    configure.add_url(ffmpeg_args, "input", *input)
TypeError: add_url() takes from 3 to 5 positional arguments but 765 were given
```

Modified Code: -

```
    def write_videofile(self, filename, fps=None, codec=None,   
                        bitrate=None, audio=True, audio_fps=44100,
                        preset="medium", pixel_format=None,
                        audio_codec=None, audio_bitrate=None,
                        write_logfile=False, verbose=True,
                        threads=None, ffmpeg_params: dict[str, str] | None = None,
                        logger='bar', over_write_output=True):
        
        # video_np = np.asarray(tuple(self.iterate_frames_array_t(fps if fps else self.fps if self.fps else (_ for _ in ()
        #                                                                                                     ).throw(Exception('Make Frame is Not Set.')))))

        audio_name, _ = os.path.splitext(filename)


        ffmpeg_options = {
            'preset': preset,
            
            **(ffmpeg_params if ffmpeg_params is not None else {}),
            **({'c:v': codec} if codec else {}),
            **({'b:v': bitrate} if bitrate else {}),
            **({'pix_fmt': pixel_format} if pixel_format else {}),
            **({'c:a': audio_codec} if audio_codec else {}),
            **({'ar': audio_fps} if audio_fps else {}),
            **({'b:a': audio_bitrate} if audio_bitrate else {}),
            **({'threads': threads} if threads else {}),
        }

        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
            suffix=".wav", prefix=audio_name + "_temp_audio_"
        ) as temp_audio_file:
            if self.audio and audio:
                self.audio.write_audio_file(temp_audio_file)
                # audio_file_name = temp_audio_file.name

                ffmpeg_options.update(
                    {"extra_inputs": [temp_audio_file.name], "acodec": "copy", "map": ["0:v", "1:a"]}
                )

            with ffmpegio.open(
                filename,
                "wv",
                fps,
                **ffmpeg_options,
                overwrite=over_write_output,
                show_log=True,) as f:
                
                for I in self.iterate_frames_array_t(fps):  # if fps else self.fps if self.fps else (_ for _ in ()
                #                                                                                             ).throw(Exception('Make Frame is Not Set.'))):
                    f.write(I)
```

I Tried Many things: -
using transcode, providing the `-i` flag with audio name While using the `ffmpegio.write`, etc.